# python-ad can not communicate with AD

Tags: python, active-directory

I am using the google api to communicate with my active directory 2008. Here is the sample code of tutorial1.

```
from ad import Client, Creds, activate

  domain = 'freeadi.org'
  user = 'Administrator'
  password = 'Pass123'

  creds = Creds(domain)
  creds.acquire(user, password)
  activate(creds)

  client = Client(domain)
  users = client.search('(objectClass=user)')
  for dn,attrs in users:
    name = attrs['sAMAccountName'][0]
    print '-> %s' % name
```

but I am getting the following error.

`ldap.LOCAL_ERROR: {'info': 'SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)', 'desc': 'Local error'}`. This is sample code from http://code.google.com/p/python-ad/wiki/TutorialOne. I have changed the username and passwd acc to my needs.

hi thanks for the reply however i am still stuck. i am join to my Ad with centrifydc. but when i run the code my log file gives me some bizzare log which i really dont have any idea since i am very new to this topic. here is the outpu of my log file:

```
Jun 28 19:22:02 sdahal1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 28 19:24:24 sdahal1 sshd13724?: Connection closed by 192.168.0.113 preauth?
Jun 28 19:24:54 sdahal1 adclient998?: INFO <fd:19 PAMVerifyPassword> audit User 'sadahal' authenticated based on Kerberos exchange to AD
Jun 28 19:24:54 sdahal1 adclient998?: INFO <fd:19 PAMIsUserAllowedAccess> audit User 'sadahal' is authorized
Jun 28 19:27:56 sdahal1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 28 19:28:04 sdahal1 python: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
Jun 28 19:28:17 sdahal1 adclient998?: INFO <fd:19 PAMVerifyPassword> audit User 'sadahal' authenticated based on Kerberos exchange to AD
Jun 28 19:28:17 sdahal1 adclient998?: INFO <fd:23 PAMIsUserAllowedAccess> audit User 'sadahal' is authorized
Jun 28 19:28:17 sdahal1 sudo:
```

Comment: That error indicates that the Kerberos encryption ticket used for the GSS LDAP connection is expired and you must explicitly renew it. It's not really a programming issue, here.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply however i am still stuck. i am join to my Ad with centrifydc. but when i run the code my log file gives me some bizzare log which i really dont have any idea since i am very new to this topic.